# Get listeners from object at runtime

Tags: java, android, events, reflection

Using `reflection` I can get member `views` in `activity`. But is there any way I can get all `listeners` attached to the `view` and listen when, for example, `view` is clicked, so I can register the `event`?

Comment: that is not the case. I need API 8+, so ListenerInfo cannot be used. i am sure you can do it via reflections.

Comment: @user2176737 Reflection deals with getting information about and executing commands on objects/types at runtime, but has nothing to do with listeners, which are not a built-in feature of the Java language.

Comment: "Using reflection I can get member views in activity" -- or you could regular APIs, like a real programmer would. Call `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` to get the main content view, and from there walk the `View` hierarchy using `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()`.

Comment: I want to get them using custom library, not interfering with the code and not knowing the id.